# groovy script for using MSTEST jenkins plugin to generate test report

Tags: jenkins, groovy, mstest

I am using Jenkins [MSBUILD](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin) plugin in a Freestyle project which is just fine. I have to specify the location of .TRX file and the test report gets generated.

Now I want to use groovy command so I can take advantage of Jenkins pipeline. can someone help me with batch/groovy command to use .TRX as a input and generate test report in Jenkins UI? I tried below but no success.

```
mstest.exe /publishresultsfile:"C:\Path_to_file\TestResult.TRX"
```

Below error occurs

```
Invalid switch "/publishresultsfile".
```

Comment: Where does groovy come in to this?

Comment: I am trying to use Jenkins Pipeline which uses groovy syntax. so even if I create a batch script first, I will have to change it to groovy to use it in pipeline.

Comment: As per the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243151.aspx) :

> Visual Studio Enterprise
> 
> The database for the team project collection resides on a Team
> Foundation Server computer. This means that you can publish test data
> only if you have Team Explorer installed and your Visual Studio user
> session is connected to a Team Foundation Server computer.

You don't seem to have an Enterprise license for Visual Studio, so the command line option you tried cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks @Pac0. However my problem is more related to make MSTest Plugin compatible with the new pipeline workflow. There is a [requirement](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32937) logged on the Jenkins site for the same.